# How to install HMM package on Weka 3.6.9?

Tags: weka

I am using Weka 3.6.9, and I am wondering how can I install HMM package into it.

All the tutorials and instructions regarding this are for Weka 3.7 which uses a Package Manager.

Could any one help me with that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give us more information? What is the HMM package? (Link?) What have you tried? Why don't you switch to Weka 3.7? How are you using Weka, command line or from Java?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to install the HMM package into any Weka before 3.7.2, where the package manager was introduced.

To install Weka 3.7 you can go to http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html, download the developer version (currently on the 3.7.10)

and then you can access the package manager by going to tools -> package manager or Ctrl+U